# Java temporarily disabling the global logger

Tags: java, logging

I'm trying to use a custom Logger for a project I'm working on and the library about that loads my JAR seems to also introduce its own logger.

My custom logger has ConsoleHandler and FileHandler, both with a custom format and both technically work.

When I log through this logger, the message, with the correct format, logs through the FileHandler fine, but through the ConsoleHandler, it is prefixed with what appears to be another logging format. This other format outputs mine logger with a WARNING level message on a even more peculiar note.

For Example, `logger.info("Hello world!")` yields:

```
[ 00:00:00 ] WARN: [00:00:00|00-00-00] INFO: Hello world!
```

This isn't exact, but you get the idea.

I have tried using the `setUseParentHandler(false)` method, which did not make a difference. It appears this logger format is even attached to the `System.out.println()` method as using it also causes this format.

I need to temporarily disable the logger this API introduced, run my code, then re-enable the logger at the end. Is this possible?

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about it? are you using an web/app server? What happens if you just use System.out.println("foo")?

Comment: It's running just locally on my machine for testing. The API has the PSVM method and loads my JAR at runtime, so I assume the logger is introduced between startup and my JAR being loaded.

If I do a system out, I get the same logging prefix at an INFO level.

Comment: mind checking if jboss-logging is in your classpath? Just a hunch

Comment: That does not appear to be the case. No sign of it the classpath, maven, or any libraries.

Comment: Hmmm... Let's see if something is indeed hijacking your System.out ;) 

Try this code: 
`PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out));
        System.setOut(ps);`

Then of course `System.out.println("Hello true out")`

Comment: Had no affect on my logger, but that did appear to cure the problem on a `System.out.println()` call. It, however, caused the SOP test I did to mix with the logger message above it.

Comment: Ok. So something is hijacking your System.out, problem is finding out what it is. 

http://projects.lidalia.org.uk/sysout-over-slf4j/ does that, but I haven't seen it in quite a while.  can't you grab a reference of System.out and inspect/debug it, so we can see what actually is the implementation type?

Comment: I mean... of course it's an instance of java.io.PrintWriter. but what's does the writer member field looks alike?

Comment: It just seems to be a `java.io.PrintStream` instance. Although that's interesting, that's not the main issue, since the logger is not affected by a force-change of the `System.out`.

Comment: Without knowing what it is, it will be quite tricky to disable it :) 
The easiest thing to do IMHO would be to inspect the System.out reference and dig deep until you see some class not from java.*, com.sun.* or com.oracle.*.

One thing we can try is to deny the API the ability of messing with System.out. With some luck, we'll see a stacktrace with the culprit class somewhere, and then it's a no-brainer ;)

Comment: We can do this enabling the java security manager - so the call for System.setOut() will fail with a SecurityException.

Runs your code passing the -Djava.security.manager system property, and let's see how this goes.

Comment: It seems to fail immediately before the API can even begin to load its dependencies.

Comment: any stacktrace? what are you using for dependency management? if you're using maven, can you do a "mvn dependency:tree"?